# Gitlab clone via ssh Permissions denied

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to clone gitlab repository via ssh on macos, bit getting "Permission denied" error.
my ssh config:

```
 Host git.cr.keessa.ru
     Preferredauthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal
```

Key id_rsa_vocal.pub added to my profile settings

This problem happened, as I think, after OS update to Sonoma 14.0 (may be it's only coincidence)

It's the same after command "ssh-add", not inly with config file.

Key was generated with command
`ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096`

(path ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal)

Here the result of command `ssh -Tv  git.cr.keessa.ru`:

```
`➜  tmp ssh -Tv  git.cr.keessa.ru
OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/yulia/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/yulia/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git.cr.keessa.ru
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to git.cr.keessa.ru port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/yulia/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/yulia/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to git.cr.keessa.ru:22 as 'yulia'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/yulia/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:m20vfhi5vO2X4HqooWbsUjsWlBgpS7J0DRFvyU0YL2U
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/yulia/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'git.cr.keessa.ru' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/yulia/.ssh/known_hosts:32
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/yulia/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal RSA SHA256:X/Chb3USz09Bds02sX6kmLjcYl32xe6TMmHsEuoI298 explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/yulia/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal RSA SHA256:X/Chb3USz09Bds02sX6kmLjcYl32xe6TMmHsEuoI298 explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
yulia@git.cr.keessa.ru: Permission denied (publickey,password).`
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `git clone git@git.cr.keessa.ru/project_name`?  You don't literally use `ssh` directly to do the clone git uses ssh for you normally.   check out https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: @UpAndAdam If SSH is rejected (due to authentication issue) how do you expect Git over SSH to work?

Comment: I'm not saying thats going to change anything but as the docs indicate not every gitlab installation is going to allow you to connect via ssh. I am not disputing the authentication issue that clearly lies at the heart of it. If you looked at the link i posted it suggests trying the exact commands you suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

The site git.cr.keessa.ru runs Gitlab. The SSH user to connect to Gitlab should be `git` (Gitlab recognizes you not by the user name but by SSH key). Try `ssh -Tv  git@git.cr.keessa.ru`. If that works change your SSH config to

```
Host git.cr.keessa.ru
     User git
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal
```

Comment: with ssh -Tv  git@git.cr.keessa.ru same result-debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@git.cr.keessa.ru: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: It seems Gitlab doesn't know your `id_rsa_vocal.pub`

Comment: I have try several times to generate and add to gitlab keys, with stable result

Comment: It seems Gitlab doesn't know your id_rsa_vocal.pub  - does you see it in logs?

Comment: @ГончароваЮлия This is the only reason for error "git@git.cr.keessa.ru: Permission denied". Everything else is fine.

Comment: @ГончароваЮлия How did you paste the public key to Gitlab? From terminal? from an editor? A pub SSH key is a single long line, any chance you pasted it split into many lines?

Comment: Previously, I copied from the command line by typing `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal.pub` . Now I using `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vocal.pub`. As a result I received `The form contains the following error: Fingerprint exists`